# Pure javascript mobile datetime picker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using Intel's appframework and am looking for a Datetime Picker. All I can find are solutions that depend on jquery. Does anyone know of a mobile datetime picker that is based on pure javascript?

Comment: If I post some code will I get less down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at "Pickaday"?

http://www.bloggermint.com/2012/10/pikaday-lightweight-standalone-javascript-datepicker/

Comment: Looks great, but I can't seem to get it to work in my cordova app. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.